# Angular JS - Variable Updating With Interval

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Do angular models work with setIntervaL?

Here's an example.. if I have

```
<p>{{number}}</p>
<button ng-click="testFunc()">TEST</button>
```

For some reason it updates WITHOUT setInterval, but like this it doesn't:

```
scope.testFunc = function(){
    setInterval(function(){
        scope.number--;
    },1000);
};
```

Without setInterval the number will update every single click, but with setInverval it won't update continuously. If I click it every 5 seconds it'll jump a bunch of numbers up (so it's running in the background but the view isn't updating).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

What's happening is that you're using `setInterval` which is outside of "Angular's world" so it's not updating the DOM. You have two options, one is a lot better than the other.

Use `$interval`. It's just like `setInterval` except it's part of the Angular world, so those changes will update your view (be sure to pass $interval into your directive).

```
scope.testFunc = function(){
    $interval(function(){
        scope.number--;
    },1000);
};
```

The second option is to call apply() on your current code to kick off a digest cycle, don't do that though since there is a better option.

Comment: Tried using $interval but it returned Error: $interval is not defined.... BUT $digest() worked

Comment: Yeah. Like I mentioned you have to pass $interval into your controller. angular.module('myCtrl', function($scope, $interval)...

Answer (score 6):

See the documentation for the interval in angular js [Interval with Angular JS](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24interval)

You don't to use the **$digest** to work with interval. See the code below:

*HTML*

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="ApplicationController">   
    <pre>Number: {{ number }}</pre>
    <button ng-click="testTimer()">Test Timer</button>
</div>
```

*JS*

```
function ApplicationController($scope,$interval) {

    $scope.number = 99999;

    $scope.testTimer = function() {
        $interval(function() {
            $scope.number--;
        }, 100);
    };  
}
```

See this example in [action here](http://jsfiddle.net/bBaa2/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Angular comes with a nice wrapper for setInterval.  Use it nearly the same way.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval

Comment: is it injected into your controller?  myApp.controller(function($scope, $interval) {...})

Answer (score 0):

$interval works definitely you can learn more about it at: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval

as a further note, instead of using `{{ number }}` try using `<p ng-model="number"></p>` to show your value instead.

Answer (score -1):

Tried using $interval but it returned Error: $interval is not defined.... BUT $digest() worked:

```
scope.testFunc = function(){
    setInterval(function(){
        scope.number--;
        scope.$digest();
    },1000);
};
```

Comment: No! Don't do this for the reasons I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: The reason why it didn't work is because you haven't injected $interval